# db2 connection with worklight adapter gives an error

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

output:

```
{"errors": ["Illegal Argument: invalid type of element"], "info": [   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,   "warnings": [   ]}
```

i use the code in .js file is

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from MITS");
function procedure1(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({   
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,        
        parameters : [param]    
    });
}


function procedure2(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "storedProcedure2",
        parameters : [param]
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about worklight, but could it be that in procedure1 you are providing a parameter, but the SQL statement doesn't expect one?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can show the code, specially WL.Client.invokeProcedure and the parameters used.